# Access denied due to invalid subscription key

Tags: azure, rest

I have used the Crossref REST API where I just send it a query in a browser address bar, which then returns results in JSON.

So I send the following URL:

```
https://api.crossref.org/works?query.bibliographic=Randomized trial of intensive early intervention for children with pervasive developmental disorder&query.author=Groen&rows=1
```

I was hoping to so the same with the Microsoft REST API, but if I send it:

I get "Access denied due to invalid subscription key".

Can I pass my key via the URL? If so how?

Or is it not that simple.

Does it need other code as well - I can code in PHP if needed, or use jQuery.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'https://api.crossref.org/works?query.bibliographic=<?php echo $title ?>&query.author=<?php echo $author ?>&rows=1&select=is-referenced-by-count,author,title,DOI,issn-type,volume,issue,link,page,abstract',

    success:function(result) {
      var total_results = result.message["total-results"];
    } 
});
```

But again, with the Microsoft API - how would I send it the keys?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is "the Microsoft REST API"? Do you mean Azure API Management? "Invalid subscription key" implies that this is an API hosted in API Management which uses this term to describe its authentication model. The following answer assumes this is the case.

You would need to be registered as a user and be given a subscription key. There is a self-service portal for doing this, which is described by [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal#managed-vs-self-hosted). It is up to the API's administrator whether you are permitted to self-service or not, so you may or may not be able to do this yourself, or you may have to request the administrator to register you. [Further documentation describes a bit how to use the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize).

When you have it, you would apply it as an http header named `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`, but the name it expects is also configurable and may have been changed, which the administrator would have to tell you.

Comment: I mean the Microsoft Project Academic Knowledge (that uses Azure): https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic-knowledge/

Comment: So I can tell by some of the phrasing and the overall registration experience that this is indeed an instance of API Management, but I wasn't aware of this specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the documentation for what I needed (the Microsoft documentation around Azure is a horrendous maze with a lot of stuff that is outdated and broken).

So the documentation is here:

https://msr-apis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/academic-search-api/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03?

I modified the Jacascript example at the bottom of page and came up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==%27jaime%20teevan%27)&count=2&attributes=Ti,Y,CC,AA.AuN,AA.AuId',
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
          // Request headers
          xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","xxxxmykeyxxxxx");
        },
        success:function(result) {

          alert(result.entities[0].Ti);

        } 
    });
});

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

The query returns all the titles for the author "jamie teevan".
Though in this example I am just outputting the first title via 'alert'. I haven't coded the rest of it yet - just wanted to know if it worked or not at this point.

Now all I need to do is work out the expression to return all the citing documents for a given title + author!!  :-/   wish me luck.